# Singular the contemporaneous covariance matrix of error terms in VAR

Tags: covariance-matrix, vector-autoregression, singular-matrix

I'm interested in the case if we have i.e. VAR(1) model:

$$
\mathbf{y}_t = \Phi \mathbf{y}_{t-1} + \mathbf{\epsilon}_t, \qquad \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{\epsilon}_t\mathbf{\epsilon}_t^T] = \Omega,
$$

where $\Omega$ is a singular matrix. I played a little bit with the simulated data and it seems that the coefficients are unstable (I suspect flat likelihood), but I can't mathematically state the problem Could you please explain this?

I attach the code:

````
T_len <- 500
Phi <- matrix(c(0.3, 0, 0, 0.2), nrow = 2)
Phi

sim_VAR <- function(T_len, Phi, singular = T){
  y <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = T_len, ncol = 2)
  y[1,] <- rnorm(2)
  u1 <- rnorm(T_len)
  u2 <- rnorm(T_len)
  if(isTRUE(singular)){
      u2 <- u1  
  }
  for(i in 2:T_len){
    y[i,] <- Phi %*% y[i-1,] + c(u1[i], u2[i])
  }
  colnames(y) <- c("x", "y")
  return(y)
}

res <- sim_VAR(T_len, Phi, singular = T)


library(vars)
res_VAR <- VAR(res, 
               p = 1,
               season = NULL)

Acoef(res_VAR)
```
````